# Fine-tuning Python Regex Fuzzy-Matching

Tags: python, regex

I am using the Python regex library (not the stanard re library) to fuzzy match terms, but am having difficulty fine-tuning the filters that limit the types of errors and permitted characters.  I have a list of terms and want to find matches across several text files while allowing an arbitrary number of underscore insertions within a word.  For example, I'd like to allow "foobar" to match to "_foobar_, "_foo_bar_", "f_o_o_b_a_r", etc.

This example returns what I want, but allows too many error types:

```
import regex

if m:= regex.search("(?b)\\b(?:test){e<=3}\\b", "_test_"):
    print(m)
else: print(None)
```

result:
`<regex.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='_test_', fuzzy_counts=(0, 2, 0)>`

The "fuzzy_counts" in the above example make it seem to me like I can limit error types to only insertions, and ultimately I'd like to limit it to only allowing inserted underscores, but I am not getting any matches when making these changes:

```
if m:= regex.search("(?b)\\b(?:test){i:_}\\b", "_test_"):
    print(m)
else: print(None)
```

result:
`None`

```
if m:= regex.search("(?b)\\b(?:test){i}\\b", "_test_"):
    print(m)
else: print(None)
```

result:
`None`

What makes these example even stranger to me is that if I add flanking spaces to the searched string, the filter limiting errors to only inserted underscores returns the intended result (but I can't expect additional characters to be in any of the text).

```
if m:= regex.search("(?b)\\b(?:test){i:_}\\b", " _test_ "):
    print(m)
else: print(None)
```

result:
`<regex.Match object; span=(1, 7), match='_test_', fuzzy_counts=(0, 2, 0)>`

Any suggestions on how to correct my refined allowed-errors filter so that I can match terms while allowing an arbitrary number of inserted underscores within word boundaries?

Comment: I think you are mistakenly using word boundaries here. Try `r"(?b)(?<![^\W_])(?:test){i:_}(?![^\W_])"`

Comment: Is there a way I can get feedback as to how my question should be improved?

Comment: Did my suggestion fix the issue?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think I'm trying to figure out SO. Why post a comment rather than an answer if you have a solution for my question?

Comment: Because it was not clear from the start what you need. It is a common issue, just use lookarounds with `_` substracted from `\w`.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is mostly correct but try these modifications

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?b)\b_*(?:test_*){e<=3}\b"
text = "_test_"

if m := regex.search(pattern, text):
    print(m)
else:
    print(None)
```

I modified the style to allow a random number of underscores before and after the word "test". This is achieved by adding _* before and after the test in the form.
You can refer to this article that contains a good example in [Python with regex](https://techscriptlab.com/mastering-fuzzy-matching-python-regex-guide/).